# Is raspberry pi 3 suitable for testing ros with pcl for computer vision purpose?

Tags: pcl, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello friends, i was little bit of confused that weather i should buy raspberry pi 3 to run ros,pcl,opencv, computer vision to accomplish computer vision tasks. I just want to test for right now. I've also seen ordoid xu4 and nvidia jetson tk1 for this task, but since they have small comunity and also cost little high. i am not sure to buy them. if they would have large community support then even if they cost little more i would buy them. but for my robotic project since i also need to interface sensors and motors, camera i need something with has got higher possibility of success, or say about which i can ask to people.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236048/is-raspberry-pi-3-suitable-for-testing-ros-with-pcl-for-computer-vision-purpose?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Pi3 obviously is not the fastest machine out there, but quite suitable for basic computer vision tasks. It really depends on the problem you're looking at. For some processing on a static scene (for instance doing blob detection), the Pi3 is suitable. If have real-time constraints and complex processing (let's say for Visual SLAM), the Pi3 probably would not be the best choice.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3